# How to add one GridColumnGroup into another GridColumnGroup in nebula grid?

Tags: eclipse, grid, swt, nebula

I have used a nebula Grid (`org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.Grid`) in my view. I have used its `GridColumnGroup` features for what they are meant. 
Now I want to design the grid GUI as in the design image below, i.e. the grid should have multi-level column groups (one `GridColumnGroup` in another `GridColumnGroup`).
[image]

As in the design image, there are two sub-ColumnGroups (namely `2-Stroke Engines` and `4-Stroke Engines`)in the outermost `GridColumnGruop` (namely engine Price List) and actual `GridColumns` are to be placed inside respective sub-ColumnGroups. How to achieve this in nebula grid ? Or any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug as stated in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240213 .

Comment: Thanks Lori, for the information. Hopefully Nebula development-team will fix the bug in upcoming version of nebula Grid.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.nebula/org.eclipse.swt.nebula.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/nebula/snippets/grid/GridSnippet6.java?root=Technology_Project&view=co

not exactly what you want but might help

Comment: No, Montaser. That is not what I had expected. I need to create the GUI as in the Pic above in my question.